# Importing a csv into mysql via command line, without creating a table beforehand

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a very large .csv file (~12gb) into mysql.

impossible to create the table before, because impossible to open the csv.

how to import a csv file without having created a table????

Comment: Why do you thing it impossible to CREATE a table - it doesn't have to have any data loaded just the columns defined. Please add first few rows of your csv file as text

Comment: Create (temporary) table with one field of TEXT type and import the file into it one row per record. Then create destination table (investigate a lot of rows for this) and parse the data into it.

Comment: *because impossible to open the csv* WHY??

Comment: very large .csv file (~12gb)

Comment: *very large .csv file (~12gb)* And? what a problem to save first 10-20 lines into another file? or use viewer which allows to view such files. [EM Editor](https://www.emeditor.com/download/), [Universal Viewer](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/uviewer/), [Large Text File Viewer](https://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=693) and so on.)

Comment: I have been waiting for Sublime Text for 15 minutes to open the file.

Comment: I proceeded according to the instructions of "Akina" ... .........USE Ameli;
LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/A2019_01.csv"  
INTO TABLE 2019_1
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES; .......................................................here is the message.....................................................::::::Query OK, 0 rows affected (39.19 sec)
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0